# C#/Mono RESTful services ArgumentException: The namespace "" is not defined

Tags: c#, rest, mono

I have an application built with REStful services, using WebGet and WebInvoke (OperationContract).

All the WebGet-method work fine; now, however, because I need a somewhat secure way of transceiving passwordsl, I chose to use WebInvoke with Method = "POST".

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = Routing.ImportImapEmailsRoute, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string ImportImapEmails(string data);


/// <summary>
/// Imports emails from an IMAP server.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The imap emails.</returns>
/// <param name="data">Data.</param>
public string ImportImapEmails(string data) {
    return "";
}
```

Every time I attempt to call this route, I get following exception:

> The namespace '' is not defined.
>   Parameter name: namespaceUri

I've narrowed it down to where the exception is thrown:

```
string GetQualifiedNamePrefix(string namespaceUri, XmlDictionaryString xNs)
    {
        string prefix = nsMgr.LookupPrefix(namespaceUri);
        if (prefix == null)
        {
            if (writeState != WriteState.Attribute)
                /* Exception thrown here */throw System.Runtime.Serialization.DiagnosticUtility.ExceptionUtility.ThrowHelperError(new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.XmlNamespaceNotFound, namespaceUri), "namespaceUri"));

            prefix = GeneratePrefix(namespaceUri, xNs);
        }
        return prefix;
    }
```

However, I can't figure out how this method is called, and/or how I can provide some sort of XML namespace to prevent this from happening in the future.
I can't put a try/catch around it, because this happens while calling the method, I have a breakpoint in my ImportImapEmails() method, which is never reached.

Details:
  macOS Sierra - Intel-based Mac Mini
  Mono 4.8
  The projects are built with .Net 4.6.1 and MSBuild

Has anyone experienced this issue before, and have they been able to fix it? Or is this a shortcoming of Mono of some sort (some web services are still unsupported or TODO)?

**EDIT:**
I've attempted to return a simple object (both an anonymous type, and an object created using the ISerializable interface, and Serializable attribute, all to know avail.
I'm still getting the same error. The only time it did function, was when I returned a simple string value?

Below is the code from the disassembly, maybe this will give someone an idea as to what exactly is going wrong?

```
00000000   ldarg.0 
00000001   ldfld Mono.Debugger.Soft.FieldInfoMirror
00000006   ldarg.1 
00000007   callvirt String NamespaceManager:LookupPrefix (String)
0000000c   stloc.0 
0000000d   ldloc.0 
0000000e   brtrue 0000004c
00000013   ldarg.0 
00000014   ldfld Mono.Debugger.Soft.FieldInfoMirror
00000019   ldc.i4.3 
0000001a   beq 00000043
0000001f   ldstr "The namespace '{0}' is not defined."
00000024   ldc.i4.1 
00000025   newarr System.Object
0000002a   dup 
0000002b   ldc.i4.0 
0000002c   ldarg.1 
0000002d   stelem.ref 
0000002e   call String System.Runtime.Serialization.SR:GetString (String, Object[])
00000033   ldstr "namespaceUri"
00000038   newobj Void System.ArgumentException:.ctor (String, String)
0000003d   call Exception ExceptionUtility:ThrowHelperError (Exception)
00000042   throw 
00000043   ldarg.0 
00000044   ldarg.1 
00000045   ldarg.2 
00000046   call String System.Xml.XmlBaseWriter:GeneratePrefix (String, XmlDictionaryString)
0000004b   stloc.0 
0000004c   ldloc.0 
0000004d   ret
```

Comment: Your method expects and returns **json** not **xml**.....

Comment: Exactly my point, I'm not calling the XML writer anywhere. I'm calling the method via ARC (Advanced REST Client), and nothing more.

Comment: You specified a  "ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json", but you returned a string instead of a serializable Json object. Same for the request where the "data" parameter shall be an object.

Comment: Ah, OK. I expected the response to be an already serialised object, not an actual one. I'll give it a try tomorrow and report back with my findings.

Comment: I've tried creating an object, both with and without the Serializable attributes and interfaces, and I still get the same exception.
I'll add the call stack with an edit to the OP.

Comment: Did you changed "string ImportImapEmails(string data);" to something like "MyJsonOutputClass ImportImapEmails(MyJsonInputClass data);" ?

Comment: No, I did not. I would expect JSON data from a client to be in string form, as I cannot expect it to be of any particular format. There may be missing or incomplete fields which would possibly cause an exception to be thrown by a parser which does not know what exactly to look for.

Comment: By declaring the RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Jsonresponse, the system only accepts text in a correct Json format that he could deserialize.

Comment: I'm sending { "data": "Test" } via POST to the application. AFAIK, this is just as valid as any other JSON I use.

Comment: @Beatsleigher, I am facing exactly what you described in your question. However, the only thing, is the service I had created had been running fine on Windows 7 ( also on Windows 10 and Server 2012 in production), now that I've tried to switch to Mono 5.*.* .NET 4.6.1 on macOS and Ubuntu 16.04, I am getting the same exact error! searching over Google, I came across this SO Question, but it seems like it's a dead end.

Comment: @Vikrant I've since mostly solved the issue. Instead of the parameter type being a string, I've created objects which are transferred as JSON. In the web request, you must not forget to explicitly add the content-type: application/json or text/json. Furthermore, you might consider returning the return values as streams. You can also manipulate some of the data with WebOperationContext.Current - the only issues I've been having since, on Linux at least, is when the content type isn't explicitly typed, the application seizes, crashes and dies. I haven't found a workaround for that yet.

Comment: Okay, I will test out the request by specifying application/JSON as content-type (also have noticed that Chrome and also the SoapUI both sent the http request with so many accept-content-type but application/JSON) and shall post answer here if it works.

Comment: @Beatsleigher: Having done what you did, it turns out the problem prevails.  For the moment, I have no solution for this and moving on with REST service from scratch from simple HttpListener based web request handler.